# CMake: Linking error when using add_library with many sources and using it in target_link_libraries

Tags: cmake, linker-errors

Full listing included at the end, here specific parts:

`add_library(common common.h utils.h utils.cc)`

and

```
add_executable(type_test type_test.cc)
target_link_libraries(type_test
        ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES}
        ast
        common
        compilation_context
        easyloggingpp
        functions
        lexer
        parser
        ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
add_test(type_test COMMAND out/type_test)
```

Now when I run `cmake . --GNinja` and later `ninja type_test`, I get:

```
    [0/1] Re-running CMake...
    -- Found LLVM 6.0.1
    -- Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: /usr/lib/llvm-6.0/cmake
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    -- Build files have been written to: /home/gru/Code/schwifty
    [1/1] Linking CXX executable out/type_test
    FAILED: out/type_test 
    : && /usr/bin/clang++  -DELPP_FEATURE_CRASH_LOG   CMakeFiles/type_test.dir/type_test.cc.o  -o out/type_test  /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a /usr/local/lib/libgtest_main.a out/libast.a out/libcommon.a out/libcompilation_context.a out/libeasyloggingpp.a out/libfunctions.a out/liblexer.a out/libparser.a -lpthread && :
    /usr/bin/ld: out/libcompilation_context.a(type.cc.o): in function `schwifty::Types::parse_type_string_internal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
    type.cc:(.text+0x18cb): undefined reference to `schwifty::utils::startswith(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
    /usr/bin/ld: type.cc:(.text+0x1c04): undefined reference to `schwifty::utils::startswith(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

`schwifty::utils::startswith` is definitely declared in `utils.h` and implemented in `utils.cc`.

Full listing available here:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
    project(schwifty)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DELPP_FEATURE_CRASH_LOG")

    set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/out)
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/out)

    find_package(PythonInterp 3.6 REQUIRED)

    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY downloads external)

    #
    # Easylogging++
    #
    if (EXISTS "external/easyloggingpp")
    else ()
        file(MAKE_DIRECTORY external/easyloggingpp)
        file(DOWNLOAD https://github.com/muflihun/easyloggingpp/archive/v9.96.4.zip
                downloads/easyloggingpp.zip)
        execute_process(COMMAND unzip downloads/easyloggingpp.zip -d downloads)
        file(GLOB easyloggingpp_files
                downloads/easyloggingpp-9.96.4/src/easylogging++.*)
        file(COPY ${easyloggingpp_files} DESTINATION external/easyloggingpp)
    endif ()

    include_directories(external/easyloggingpp)
    add_library(easyloggingpp external/easyloggingpp/easylogging++.cc)

    #
    # Local lib targets
    #

    add_library(ast ast.h ast.cc)

    add_library(ast_compare_visitor ast_compare_visitor.h ast_compare_visitor.cc)

    add_library(classes classes.h classes.cc)

    add_library(codegen
            codegen.h
            codegen.cc
            codegen_common.h
            codegen_common.cc
            expression_type_visitor.cc
            expression_type_visitor.h)

    add_library(common common.h utils.h utils.cc)

    add_library(compilation_context
            compilation_context.h
            compilation_context.cc
            enum.h
            enum.cc
            errors.h
            errors.cc
            operators.h
            operators.cc
            type.h
            type.cc)

    add_library(functions functions.h functions.cc)

    add_library(jit jit.cc jit.h)

    add_library(lexer lexer.cc lexer.h lexer_common.cc lexer_common.h)

    add_library(parser parser.h parser.cc)

    add_library(runtime runtime.cc runtime.h)

    add_library(type_inference
            type_inference.h
            type_inference.cc
            symbol_visitor.cc
            symbol_visitor.h
            type_inference_visitor.cc
            type_inference_visitor.h)

    #
    # External lib targets
    #

    find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

    message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
    message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

    include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

    llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs all)

    find_package(FMT REQUIRED CONFIG)

    #
    # Schwifty main executable
    #

    add_executable(schwifty schwifty.cc)
    target_link_libraries(schwifty
            ${llvm_libs}
            ast
            classes
            codegen
            common
            compilation_context
            easyloggingpp
            fmt::fmt
            functions
            lexer
            parser
            runtime
            type_inference)

    #
    # Testing
    #

    enable_testing()
    find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

    find_package(Threads)

    include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    add_executable(codegen_test codegen_test.cc)
    target_link_libraries(codegen_test
            ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES}
            ${llvm_libs}
            easyloggingpp
            ast
            classes
            codegen
            common
            compilation_context
            fmt::fmt
            functions
            jit
            lexer
            parser
            runtime
            type_inference
            ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
    add_test(codegen_test COMMAND out/codegen_test)

    add_executable(lexer_test lexer_test.cc)
    target_link_libraries(lexer_test
            ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES}
            ast
            common
            compilation_context
            easyloggingpp
            functions
            lexer
            parser
            fmt::fmt
            ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
    add_test(lexer_test COMMAND out/lexer_test)

    add_executable(parser_test parser_test.cc)
    target_link_libraries(parser_test
            ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES}
            ast
            ast_compare_visitor
            compilation_context
            common
            easyloggingpp
            functions
            lexer
            parser
            fmt::fmt
            ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
    add_test(parser_test COMMAND out/parser_test)

    add_executable(type_test type_test.cc)
    target_link_libraries(type_test
            ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES}
            ast
            common
            compilation_context
            easyloggingpp
            functions
            lexer
            parser
            ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
    add_test(type_test COMMAND out/type_test)

    add_executable(type_inference_test type_inference_test.cc)
    target_link_libraries(type_inference_test
            ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES}
            easyloggingpp
            ast
            classes
            common
            compilation_context
            functions
            fmt::fmt
            lexer
            parser
            runtime
            type_inference
            ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
    add_test(type_inference_test COMMAND ./out/type_inference_test)

    add_test(NAME end_to_end_tests
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CTEST_SOURCE_DIRECTORY}
            COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} end_to_end_tests.py)
```

And all code available here: https://bitbucket.org/gruszczy/schwifty/src/default/

Comment: Try `target_link_libraries(compilation_context common)`

Comment: Hmm.. That worked. I am a little surprised it did though. Ordering matters?

Comment: Yes, ordering matters, thats why you have to tell CMake that `compilation_context` uses symbols from `common`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're not following modern CMake best practices. Your libraries don't link to anything, only your executables do. When compiling by hand, this is how one would do it, because static libraries don't link to other static libraries, only executables do. In CMake however, the world works a bit different.

You should always link to libraries you use, and **only** what you directly use, **not** what you *indirectly* use. For both executable and library targets. The targets in CMake form a hierarchy of libraries and executables. CMake keeps track of what needs what and links accordingly. For example, if you executable `exe` requires library `liba` which itself requires library `libb`, you should NOT link your executable to both `liba` and `libb`, but instead link `liba` to `libb` and only link your executable to `liba`. CMake will do the rest and resolve the hierarchy to form a correct linking command.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I have very little experience with `cmake` (used `bazel` most of my career and now `buck`). I would love to improve. Would you be able to give me some advice how I can improve my cmake? I posted an old version in codereview (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196243/cmake-for-a-toy-programming-language), which I think was even worse, but didn't get any comments.

Answer (score 1):

Linking order matters for static libraries with bfd ld. (not sure about gold). libcommon.a is read, processed and dropped before `libcompilation_context.a` is brought around which needs symbols declared in `libcommon.a`.

The old fashion way to fix this was `ld c.o -lcommon -lcompilation_context -lcommon`. `cmake`'s `LINK_INTERFACE_MULTIPLICITY` should (I think) solve your problem.

Comment: I'm curious: this code linked on macos, but not on Ubuntu. Is there a difference in how linker works on Unix vs Linux? I used clang in both.

Comment: Yup, ld64 keeps all symbols from all archives around. bfd ld drops the archive and all of it's symbols as soon as it's finished processing it.